# Rewrite rule with similar pattern doesn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file to redirect a path to a different path:

```
RewriteRule ^tours/$    /tours/page/1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

I also want to rewrite specific pages in that path as some pages are removed and Google Search Console alerts a 404 notification:

```
RewriteRule ^tours/live-in-las-vegas-2020/$                 /tours/live-in-las-vegas-2019/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

I cannot get the second one to redirect to the correct page. It's definitely the correct url, I tried to remove the "L", change sequence of the lines and removed the "tours" path.

I've got this at the top of my file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.rwdb.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.rwdb.info/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [NE,L,R=301]

Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

And I've got this one to prettify my URLs from PHP

```
RewriteRule ^tours/page/([^/]*)/$    /index.php?type=tour&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tours/([^/]*)/$         /index.php?type=tour-detail&seo_link=$1 [L]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `example.com/tours/live-in-las-vegas-2020/` work fine from your browser?

Comment: Both your patterns only match one specific URL path from beginning to end, so the order of these two rules should not matter here. Do you have any other rewriting directives?

Comment: @anubhava, yes but it goes to a 404 page, which is correct as the page doesn't exist anymore. /tours/example/ works fine for all existing pages.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated my post, can any of this be related? Sorry I am very new in regex.

Answer (score 1):

I found the resolution, apologies I was trying for so long and after posting I found the solution. It's a matter of sequence. The specific redirects should be placed above the prettify pattern.